# Add default value in sql with where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to define a default value using a where clause:

```
Name  |  Value   
------| ------  
Jeff  |  Green  
Paul  |  Red  
Seb   |  Blue

ALTER TABLE Blokes
MODIFY Name DEFAULT Green WHERE Name='Jeff'
```

Something along these lines.

(apologies for the poor formatting but I couldn't get the table to work)

Edit: I am looking to update future entries automatically using DEFAULT. The DB in use is Oracle.

Edit 2: I was unable to find what I needed so I have gone with the option to update the data in a php script.

Comment: A default value applies to **new** rows. If you want to change the value for existing rows, you need to use `UPDATE`. Also: which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Looking at my question, I now see how unclear it is. Apologies for that. I will be updating existing columns with an update, but I also wish to update any future entries automatically. The DB is Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE
        Blokes
ADD     Name AS (CASE WHEN Name ='Jeff' THEN 'N' ELSE Name END)
```

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, but not been back in the office for a couple of days. I tried this method but as I worded my question poorly, it wasn't quite what I needed. I have since opted to alter what I need in one of the php scripts which use the data. Thank you for your answer though.